Ошибка : Class "EvTimer" not found
Весь день не могу найти решение проблемы "Class "EvTimer" not found"


<?php
$w1 = new EvTimer(2, 0, function () {
    echo "2 секунды прошло\n";
});
?>



Буду благодарен если подскажите решение.
Заранее спасибо.

А вы данный модуль установили? Если верить документации, его надо отдельно ставить.

Если модуль установлен, то добавьте \  в название, чтобы получилось new \EvTimer. У меня только так работает со "встроенными" классами, иначе пытается найти их в Laravel'е.
